# What is the difference between $x$ and $\{x\}$ when $x$ itself is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've already asked this a part of another question, but thought it'd be easier to elaborate a bit more on my concern.

Let $x$ be a set. What is the difference between $x$ and $\{x\}$? I get that the latter is a set consisting of a single element - namely $x$, but what is the difference?

For example, we can have $x$ to be the set $\{1\}$, then $\{x\}=\{\{1\}\}$. Aren't those $2$ expressions the same?

Another problem are the brackets - when we have a set, do we always have to surround him with brackets, for instance, can we have $x$ to be the set $2$?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you understand the distinction between the emptyset and the set containing the emptyset ($\{\}$ versus $\{\{\}\}$)?

Comment: Yes, the former contains nothing, while the latter contains the empty set

Comment: Les trivial example: $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,\ldots \}$  has infinite many elements: **all** the natural numbers, while $\{ \mathbb N \}$ has only one element: **the** set of all natural numbers.

Comment: So then why do you think that $\{1\}=\{\{1\}\}$? That would only be true if $1=\{1\}$, and what's your reason for believing that?

Comment: You may find [John von Neumann's construction of the ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) interesting. We start by defining $0=\{\}$, then $1=\{0\} = \{\{\}\}$, $2 = \{0, 1\}$, $3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$, etc.

Comment: I see, I didn't see the difference between sets and elements grouped together

Comment: See also the section Quine Atioms in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement).

Comment: *"I see, I didn't see the difference between sets and elements grouped together"* -- "elements grouped together" are not a mathematical object. A set *is*. You can't say that "$a,b,c$" *is* anything mathematically, because it's not a single object. But $\{a,b,c\}$ is an object, and you can talk about its properties.

Comment: One of the most popular mathematical "trivia", even among people not having much common with math, an analogy to something obvious or trivial, is saying that $1+1=2$. Maybe we could popularize that $1+1=\{1\}$, which looks even better for me :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Think of the brackets as a bag you put things in. Then $\{1\}$ is a bag containing the number $1$. But  $\{\{1\}\}$ is a bag containing a bag containing the number $1$. So two bags, one inside the other. These are different. Physically different if you think real paper bags.

Comment: To the OP: note that this is a limited intuition. In particular, it's really more about [*multisets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) than sets, since a bag containing two empty bags is different from a bag containing one empty bag. Still, it's quite useful for thinking about this sort of issue at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate this intuitive definition

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ is more fun; one has cardinality 0, the other 1.

Answer (score 4):

$$\{1\} $$ is a set whose the unique element is the integer $1$

$$\{\{1\}\} $$ is a set whose the unique element is the set $\{1\} $.

Comment: I see, thanks! But what about the brackets bit - do we have to always put them around a set to indicate that it's actually a set and not, say, some integers?

Comment: @asdf In response I would ask you, what do you consider to be the difference between "a set" and "some integers"?

Comment: @DavidZ it is clear there is a difference between an element and a set.

Comment: It is clear to most of us here, yes, but I'm specifically asking @asdf.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem - I basically made no difference, thank you all

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Now I wonder, what the difference really is? I mean, every element possible is a set too, right? (we start from defining integers like John von Neumann in his construction, then we build "the rest" of sets and mathematics). And every set $X$ is always element of some set, for example of $\{X\}$ or its own power set. So, aside of differentiating a set from his own element in these special cases, can we say that, in general, there is any difference between sets and elements?

Comment: In modern mathematics, everything is a set! So yes, 2 is a set and it is { {}, {{}}}. For natural numbers, the set is defined by 0={} (emptyset), then n+1=n cup {n}. Computing a few terms can clarify the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have $x=\varnothing$, then $0=\#x\neq \#\{x\}=1$. So clearly both sets are not the same.

Edit: With $\#S$ I refer to the cardinality of a set $S$, i.e. in the finite case the number of elements in $S$.

Comment: Here $\#$ is being used to denote "the cardinality of" a set, i.e. the size of the set in terms of how many elements it contains.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you, I should have explained the notation.

Comment: @asdq You could still edit your answer to explain the notation.

Comment: @DavidZ Since it is explained right below, I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @asdq On StackExchange [comments are temporary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/305499). You shouldn't rely on comments sticking around. It's explicitly part of the StackExchange usage guidelines that improvements suggested in comments should be incorporated into the question/answer itself.

Comment: @R.M. I see, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting confused between the name of a set and its description.
When we write $A=\{x\}$, we mean $A$ is a set and inside set $A$, we have an element $x$.

Now if I define another set $B=\{A\}$, 
then $B$ is a set and inside set $B$, we have an element $A$, which is also a set. In this case, $B$ is a set of sets.

If you want to refer to the latter set, write
its name $B$, or
its description $\{A\}$.

For your last question, YES, we surround the elements of the set by curly braces {}, which also ensures unorderdness and non-repeatability.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing to make it clear that $\{B\}$ is a perfectly fine thing to write, it's just an entirely different mathematical object from $B$.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have removed dos and donts.

Comment: After the edit, I think this is a really nice way of describing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a practical difference when you think about how you might *use* these sets - namely as a domain of functions. A function that takes a number is not the same as a function that takes a set.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be helpful to imagine the difference in concrete terms - say in terms of a computer data structure.  Suppose we represent sets using linked lists *[disregard for the moment that we cannot represent infinite sets this way]*.  Then $x$ is (the head pointer of) a sequence of nodes, where each node has a pointer to an element of $x$ and a pointer to the next node in the sequence.  Then {$x$} is (the head pointer of) *a single node*, whose element pointer points to (the head node of) the sequence of nodes representing $x$.  Clearer?