# is {{}} or {Ø} an empty set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that (I might be wrong):

- Symbol for empty or null set :  {Ø} or {}
- Null or empty set is 'subset of all sets' as well as 'empty or null set' set
- So, { {} } is same as { Ø }

I just want to know { {} } or { Ø } is an empty set or not ? And if yes then we can conclude that if a set contains a only null set which is by definition always true then it must be a null or empty set.

(Here I am assuming empty and null are same, because I've read that they sometimes taken as different.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty set does not belong to empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302064/empty-set-does-not-belong-to-empty-set)

Comment: >Symbol for empty or null set : $\{Ø\}$or $\{\}$

this is wrong. It should be "symbol for the empty set is $Ø$ or $\{\}$

Empty set is a subset of all set by definition of a subset.

we say $A$ is a subset of $B$ if some element $a$ belongs to $ A$ then $a$ belongs to $B$.

Now since empty set contains no elements the above statement is vacuously true. But depending on that you cannot write empty set as $\{Ø\}$ or $\{\{\}\}$

Comment: $\{Ø\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ is equal to the set which contains empty set. In modern-day we do not use the word "set" for these kind of sets. sets which contains sets are called **collection of sets** , **family of sets**.

Answer (score 2):

A set whose only element is the empty set is not empty (an empty set contains no element).

Think of sets a boxes. If you put a small empty box into a big box, the big box isn't empty anymore. It doesn't matter if the small box is empty or not. That's the beauty of the $\{\;\}$ notation -- it "looks" like a box.

If you remember that $\varnothing$ is just another name for $\{\;\}$, then you immediately know that $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are not the same thing, but $\{\varnothing\}$  and $\{\{\;\}\}$ are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that (I might be wrong):
>
> - Symbol for empty or null set :  {Ø} or {}

You write the empty set as "Ø" or "{}" so your first notation, "{Ø}" is already *a set containing the empty set*!

So don't mix:

- the empty set: "Ø" or "{}"
- a set containing the empty set: "{Ø}" or "{ {} }"

> So, { {} } is same as { Ø }

Correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are the same and it is a set witch contains an empty set as an element.

But symbols   {Ø} and {} are not the same. Second one is an empty set or $\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

The sets you have written down are the same. Neither is empty since each has just one element: the empty set.

Related: [What is the difference between $x$ and $\{x\}$ when $x$ itself is a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620616/what-is-the-difference-between-x-and-x-when-x-itself-is-a-set/2620621#2620621)

Comment: "The sets you have written down are the same" — there is quite a number of sets written in the question, not all being the same.

Comment: @lisyarus Before the edit there were just two sets listed - the two in the paragraph beginning "I just ..."